# Links to download DoD certificate authority (CA) certificates

Tags: ssl, cac

I have found 2 articles on how to configure an Apache web server for CAC card authentication. 
The 2 articles are

https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/apache-cac-configuration.html

https://wiki.nps.edu/display/~mcgredo/Apache+Configuration+for+CAC+Card+Authentication

both these articles have step of a shell script that downloads the CA certs using the the following wget link commands

**script 1**

```
wget http://dodpki.c3pki.chamb.disa.mil/rel3_dodroot_1024.p7b
wget http://dodpki.c3pki.chamb.disa.mil/rel3_dodroot_1024.p7b
wget http://dodpki.c3pki.chamb.disa.mil/rel3_dodroot_2048.p7b
wget http://dodpki.c3pki.chamb.disa.mil/dodeca.p7b
wget http://dodpki.c3pki.chamb.disa.mil/dodeca2.p7b
```

**script 2**

```
wget http://dodpki.c3pki.chamb.disa.mil/dodeca2.cac
wget http://dodpki.c3pki.chamb.disa.mil/rel3_dodroot_2048.cac
wget http://dodpki.c3pki.chamb.disa.mil/dodeca.cac
```

Does anyone have the current working links to download the DoD CA Certs in p7b or cac format

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen https://iase.disa.mil/pki-pke/Pages/tools.aspx?

You can use the installer to install all Root and Intermediate certificate in your windows.  You can then export these certificates to files.  After that you can use OpenSSL to convert the the PKCS7 (p7b) format.

Here is a reference on how.  https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO26449